# change sshpass to a more secure solution

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I have a python script which contains the following function:

```
def upload2server(file):
    host_name = 'example.ex.am.com'
    port_num = '432'
    user_name = 'user'
    password = 'passw'
    web_path = '/example/files/'
    full_webpath = user_name + '@' + host_name + ':' + web_path + args.key
    pre_command = 'sshpass -p "' + password + '" scp -P' + ' ' + port_num + ' ' 

    scp_comm = pre_command + file + ' ' + full_webpath 

    os.system(scp_comm)
```

I'd have 2 questions:

1. How unsecure is that if I run this script from a remote network using port-forwarding?
2. Which ways could I make this uploading more secure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would generate an SSH keypair for each host and then you can totally forget about using the password in your scp command. Having your password inline isn't a problem per say but it does mean that your password will get recorded in the ~/.bash_history file of that user.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it clearly: I generate an ssh keypair: ssh-keygen -t -rsa I get a public and a private key. I copy the public key onto the server, and leave the private on my client computer. Now I can authenticate securely. My question: If I would like to connect to the server from my laptop, pc, two cell phones, tablet, should I generate for every device or copy that private key to every device I generated for the first time? Thanks

Comment: Yup you got it @Marci !  You should generate a different key for each device, and copy their public keys to the servers authorized hosts directory.

Comment: The task for which I need this is a mobile application which makes an ssh connection with a server. Should I make this whole ssh key generating and copying it to the server stuff when they download the app, so in the android/java code?

Comment: or the solution is not that simple?

Comment: I don’t think I would use SCP to move files from an android app.  If someone takes your app apart, and gets access to the keys they can log into your server.  I would probably make an api that handles this.  There should be some good examples of doing that with Flask.